# Column Chart: Click event to only trigger on drilldown series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working on a 2 level column chart. I want to perform a task like showing an alert on clicking each bar on chart on drilldown series only. I have found this:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, but it fires for parent series too. Can we force this click event to work only on 2nd level series (that appears after drilldown)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `this` value of your `click` event will be a object with no values if you click a parent, you could do a check for an `x` value (or similar)  to see if it was a destroyed parent or you are clicking a currently available point. Make sure it's a value you know your point will have.

For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5en05Ld/1/)):

```
var UNDEFINED;

$('#container').highcharts({
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        if(this.x != UNDEFINED)
                            alert("It's alive!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
});
```

If it only concerns a specific series you could also consider adding the event code to those specific series, instead of doing this general code for all series.

Comment: Not working I am using highmaps and used your code but when i click on main chart alert is triggered i only want to triggered when dilldown chart lables is clicked please suggest me some.